# How to bind a conditional panelCount to a question type of 'paneldynamic' in SurveyJs

Tags: javascript, angular, surveyjs

In my survey in SurveyJs, I'm attempting to implement a question with the type 'paneldynamic', which has the following structure:

```
{
        type: "paneldynamic",
        name: "9.2",
        visible: false,
        visibleIf: "{9.a.n} > 0",
        title: "When did you give birth?",
        enableIf: "{9.a.n} > 0",
        requiredIf: "{9.a.n} > 0",
        templateTitle: "Date of birth:",
        templateElements: [
          {
            type: "text",
            name: "9.2.1",
            inputType: "date",
            maxValueExpression: "today()",
            titleLocation: 'hidden'
          },
        ],
        panelCount: "{9.a.n}"
}
```

where Question 9a is a number entry. I want the number of panels on this question to vary depending on the answer given to Q9a, but with this question structure the survey does not appear to bind the value of 9a to the actual panel count.

I've been unable to find anything in the documentation, and have tried variants such as `"bindings: { "panelCount": "9.a.n" }` which also don't seem to work.

How can I correctly set the variable panelCount property?

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to create a custom function and calculate the number of panels based on another question answer. For example: https://plnkr.co/edit/iYNMt7JRPOh2dTOy.

```
Survey.Serializer.addProperty("paneldynamic", {
     name: "panelCountExpression:expression",
     onExecuteExpression: (obj, res) => {       
       if(res !== undefined) {
          obj.panelCount = res;
       }
     }
});
var json = { 
 "pages": [
  {
   "name": "page1",
   "elements": [
     {
     "type": "text",
     "name": "question1",
     "inputType":"number",
     "min": 0,
     "max": 5,
     "defaultValue":"2"
    },
    {
     "type": "paneldynamic",
     "name": "question2",
     "panelCountExpression":"{question1}",
      "templateElements": [
      {
       "type": "text",
       "name": "question3"
      }]
    }
   ]
  }
 ],
};
```

I also recommend that you review the following:

- Blogpost (the example was taken from it): [SurveyJS Library — Calculate Properties and Hide Elements With Expressions and Functions](https://medium.com/@surveyjs/surveyjs-library-calculate-properties-and-hide-elements-with-expressions-and-functions-557281b1e9e7).
- Documentation: [Conditional Logic and Dynamic Texts](https://surveyjs.io/form-library/documentation/design-survey-conditional-logic).

Thanks